# Android how can open searchview when user click toolbar

Tags: java, android, searchview

I want to open searchview when user click toolbar. How I can do it

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_items,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.searchHint));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: It should auto open. Can you share your menu item ?

Comment: it is openning when I click search button which ı define as item in toolbar. But I want to open it when click toolbar.

Comment: On the toolbar click listener set searchView.setIconified(false), so it will expand the search view.

Comment: @Abdul it is not working

Comment: and toolbar click listener is triggering ? Can you verify ?

Answer (score 1):

So basically I implemented the whole thing at my end and it is working. Remember that widget should be from AndroidX.

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var searchView: SearchView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnClickListener).setOnClickListener {
            searchView?.onActionViewExpanded()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu)
        searchView = (menu.findItem(R.id.search).actionView as SearchView)
        return true
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClickListener"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Menu resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

On the button click, it will expand the search view.
You can replace that with your own click listener.

Answer (score 0):

override this method for handle clicks.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case android.R.id.search:
                    openSearch();
                    return false;
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

add the collapseActionView value to your app:showAsAction attribute to ensure your Menu Item uses the Collapsible Action View specified

inside Menu.xml add this

> app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

and after that

> MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
> SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
>
> ```
> searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new onClickListener(){
>     public void onClick(View v){
>       //TODO react to the button press.
>     }
>  });
> ```
>
> Blockquote

Comment: Thank you for answer but I do not have problem with this. I want to open searchview, when user click toolbar.